# Detect Text from the Image

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, python-imaging-library, distortion

I have this image and i want to detect the text of the image.

[image]

Can you help me with the Python Code.
I have done till here.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("temp_temp.png")
# resize to make more clearer
m = 6.5
img = img.resize((int(img.size[0]*m), int(img.size[1]*m))).convert('RGBA')
# img.show()
pixdata = img.load()
limit = 75

for y in range(img.size[1]):
    print("a",y)
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        if pixdata[x, y][0] < limit:
            # make dark color black
            pixdata[x, y] = (170, 170, 170, 255)
        else:
            # make light color white
            pixdata[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, 255)
img.convert('L')
img.show()            
img.save("temp_temp1.png")     
# Now correcting the Radial Distortion
```

Comment: Have you tried pytesseract ?

Comment: Use google vision

Comment: No Ocr will work over the Image till we preprocess it. We have to first identify the digits inside it and after that we can apply Pytesseract and vision over it. I already tried with the OCR and that is not working because the vertical lines in the image are of the same color.

Comment: @saurabheights can you help here.